# Stripe Intent API Hold Card and then Charge Not Working

Tags: android, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to implement a pretty straightforward flow for my product:

1. Customer adds card to his account
2. Customer makes a request -> Create a hold on his card for the request price
3. On request delivered -> Execute the initial hold made on the card

Upon reading through loads of docs on Stripe's new Intent API, this seemed pretty simple.

A. Create a Stripe customer

`stripe.customers.create({ email: user.email, description:`Customer for ${user.email}`});`

B. Attach a card (payment method) to the customer, create a `setup intent` with this card to authorize future charges

`stripe.setupIntents.create({ 'customer': customer_id, 'payment_method': paymentMethodId });`

C. On a request made by the customer, create paymentIntent with `capture_method` set to `manual`

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
    'amount': price * 100, //convert shekels to agorot
    'currency': 'ILS',
    'customer': customer_id,
    'payment_method': payment_method,
    'payment_method_types': ['card'],
    'capture_method': 'manual'
});
```

D. On request delivered, simply `capture` the original `paymentIntent` created in step C.

`const captureHoldIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture(paymentIntentId);`

The issue I'm getting actually is occurring between steps C and D:

**Failed to save transaction for user_id KAJSD92 error Error: This PaymentIntent could not be captured because it has a status of requires_confirmation. Only a PaymentIntent with one of the following statuses may be captured: requires_capture.**

While I understand this error message, my confusion is as to why the `paymentIntent` created in step C doesn't change to the `requires_capture` status and is instead always `require_confirmation`, even though it has already been confirmed?

Answer (score 11):

The missing piece was calling `paymentIntents.confirm` to "confirm" that the service actually wants to place a hold on the card. After that, the intents status was changed to `requires_capture` which allowed me to call the `capture` method.

1. Create

```
const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
            'amount': price * 100, //convert shekels to agorot
            'currency': 'ILS',
            'customer': customer_id,
            'payment_method': payment_method,
            'payment_method_types': ['card'],
            'capture_method': 'manual'
        });
```

2. Confirm

`const confirmPaymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.confirm(intentId);`

3. Capture

`const captureHoldIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture(intentId);`

Comment: You can also add the `confirm` option to `true` when creating the payment intent. Step 2 becomes useless.
More info: https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent-confirm

Comment: Good catch @sebj

Comment: Adding to @Sebj answer: You can skip step 2 by using `'confirm': true` and skip step 3 by removing `'capture_method': 'manual'`. Stripe will default  to `'capture_method': 'automatic'` resulting in the payment intent being captured immediately.

Comment: @LobsterBaz - whats the advantage to that? How is it different to just charging a regular payment?

Comment: How and where should I add card information like cvv,card number?

Answer (score 0):

need to add '**confirm:true**' while creating the paymentIntents

```
const payment = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
                amount,
                currency: "USD",
                description: "Delicious empanadas",
                payment_method: id,
                confirm:true,
                payment_method_types: ['card'],
                capture_method: 'manual',
            });
```

then do capture

```
 const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.capture(stripe_payment_intent_id, {
            amount_to_capture: AMOUNT_XXX,
        })
```